# How does one detect a button release with Unity's new input system?

Tags: unity, c#, input, controllers

I'm attempting to upgrade my technique from the classic input methods to the new Input System for Unity; but I'm finding it a little sprawling and unhelpful so far.

I know that if I have an action, let's call it `Fire`, and I want it to come from a variety of input devices and call a specific function, let's say `Obliterate(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)` when it's used, all I have to do is something like this:

```
controls.Player.Fire.performed += ctx => Obliterate(ctx);
```

However, what if I'm attempting to detect if the button has been not pressed, but released, possibly after some delay? I can't find anything on that, maybe I'm overlooking it. Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: It depends on the context/configuration. This docs link may help you get better understanding - https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Interactions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Hold Interaction, then the Cancelled event gets called when the button is released, with the Performed event happening if the item is held for the given duration.

[image: Image showing the Hold Interaction]

As of Unity 2022.3.10f1 (my current version), Cancelled also gets called on release even after you've held for the full amount of time, [which seems counter to Internet wisdom](https://forum.unity.com/threads/learning-new-inputsystem-when-and-how-is-the-cancelled-callback-used.969501/).

Answer (score 4):

OK, here's what I've figured out. The type of the action needs to be Value, not Button or Pass Through—this can be changed in the editor by selecting the action from the list; there's a drop down available in its settings. (Don't forget to save the asset and regenerate the C# code.)

Once this is done, the button behaves more like an axis, and invokes `.canceled` on its release. For a hold action, you can use a coroutine; simply set a control boolean to true and call `StartCoroutine` with it in your `.performed` callback. When the button or control is released, it will trigger `.canceled`, which can call another function that toggles the boolean back to false, and breaks the internal control loop in your coroutine allowing it to exit.

This allows for one action to be performed for a brief press, and another to be performed after a hold in continuum, until the button is released.

Comment: There are `started`, `performed` and `canceled` events. `canceled` is called when the input ends, `started` when input starts, `performed` - this one isn't necessary called every frame, for example, on gamepad when you move a stick `performed` is called only when the value changes. There are processors that modify behaviour as well if you add them. I don't understand what you mean by `StartCoroutine` in `performed` callback, I feel like that is going to create a non-intended behaviour.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ I think this would be worth writing up as your own answer.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ the coroutine begins after a hold action is performed, doing what I want to be done; and ceases after the button is released with a canceled action. That's all, it's very intentional.

Comment: I am not sure the function signature it's expecting. I changed it to value and now it says Method 'PlayerController.OnSkill1' not found, even though I already have OnSkill1 with the InputAction.CallbackContext ctx as param.

Comment: Figured it out; it expects InputValue instead of context, and can be detected by isPressed

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your own answer, if you feel that it answeres your question.